# How to solve $dY_t = dt + 2 \sqrt{Y_t} dW_t$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am trying to solve:
$ dY_t = dt + 2 \sqrt{Y_t} dW_t$ with $Y_0 = y_0 > 0$, where $W$ is one dimentional standard Brownian motion. Using the clue in [this linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073358/solve-the-sde-dx-t-frac12-x-t-dt-db-t), I use the substitution, $Z_t=\exp(-\sqrt{Y_t})$. I derive the derivatives as follows.

\begin{align*}
f(y)&=\exp(-\sqrt{y}),\\
f'(y)&=\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{y})}{-2\sqrt{y}},\\
f''(y) &= \frac{-2\sqrt{y}\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{y})}{-2\sqrt{y}}-\exp(-\sqrt{y})\frac{-1}{\sqrt{y}}}{4y},\\
&=\exp(-\sqrt{y}) \frac{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}}{4y}.
\end{align*}

Using Ito's formula, I get:
\begin{align*}
dZ_t &= f'(Y_t)dY_t+\frac12f''(Y_t)4Y_t dt,\\
dZ_t &= \frac{-Z_t}{2 \sqrt{Y_t}}dt -Z_tdW_t+\frac12Z_t\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{Y_t}}\right)dt\\
&= \frac12Z_t dt-Z_tdW_t.
\end{align*}

The solution is $Z_t = Z_0 \exp(-W_t)$, or $Y_t=\left(\sqrt{Y_o}+W_t\right)^2.$, or using $X_t=\sqrt{Y_t}$, $X_t-X_0=W_t$.

Is the above solution correct? I am confused because the last equation corresponds to $dX_t=dW_t$, which is different from the equation $dX_t=\frac{1}{2X_t}dt+dW_t$ - do they both give rise to the same SDE?

Comment: this is discussed here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227569/find-closed-form-solution-to-the-sde-dx-t-dt-2-sqrtx-t-dw-t?rq=1