# Can a stochastic process correspond to multiple SDE's?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227569/find-closed-form-solution-to-the-sde-dx-t-dt-2-sqrtx-t-dw-t?rq=1), and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073358/solve-the-sde-dx-t-frac12-x-t-dt-db-t?noredirect=1&lq=1), it is clear that the solution of the one-dimensional SDE $dX_t = \frac{1}{2 X_t} dt + dB_t$ is $X_t-X_0=B_t$. This is also the Bessel process. I am confused by the solution, as it is equivalent ti $d X_t = dB_t$. How can there be two equivalent SDE representations of the same stochastic process $X_t=W_t$?

Comment: @saz: Can you please help me with this one? Thanks for your answers on SDE's!

Comment: I am not quite sure your conclusion that $X_t - X_0 = B_t$ is correct.  It looks like you have $X_t^2 = (X_0 + B_t)^2$, but that doesn't imply $X_t = X_0 + B_t$.  In fact, if $dX_t = \frac 1{2X_t}dt + dB_t$ then $X$ can't even be a local martingale.